# Add a custom link/button to a visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom link on the opportunity object which points to an external site. Is it possible to add this custom link to a visualforce page?

The solution I came up with was to copy the url salesforce creates for this custom link, and paste it in the page. It looks something like this:

```
<a href="https://{!hostname}/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=00bE0000000YbK3&eid={!opportunity.Id}&ic=1">my custom link</a>
```

This works fine, however, it won't work once it's in a managed package installed on other servers because the lid param will be different (the custom link id). Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build off the answer from danieljimenez, the `$Action` global variable provides access to the button/link objects. From there you need to use the `URLFOR` function to get it into a usable form. Then you can either put it into the `action` param of a command button, or use it as you'd like anywhere else in your markup.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.My_Obj__c.My_custom_link)}" value="My custom button"/>
```

or

```
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Calculation__c.My_custom_link)}">My link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about putting the URL of the link in a field on the opportunity object and then creating an output link on your VF page?

Paul

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not work because the external site needs to open within Salesforce (as if the Behavior setting on the custom link is set to "Display in existing window without sidebar"), so I don't think it can be done without creating a custom link

Comment: I agre, I think it sounds like a custom link all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Look under $Action. Buttons and links are available via that global variable. For example `$Action.Opportunity.CustomLink`

Answer (score 0):

create New Contact (Salesforce button target _blank)

```
<apex:commandLink target="_blank" 
styleClass="btn" 
style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" 
action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact)}"
value="Create New Contact" />
```